# Finding largest value in a column with grouping and displaying entire data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to find the largest value in the 'Fertility rate' column but grouping it by year.

I did this:

```
largest = df_subset.groupby(['Year'])['Fertility rate, total (births per woman)'].nlargest(5)
print(largest)
```

This works but the only problem is that I want to see all the columns and not just Year and Fertility rate.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the indexes and then ask for them from the original DataFrame using iloc:

```py
inds = df_subset.groupby(['Year'])['Fertility rate, total (births per woman)'].nlargest(5).index.levels[1]
largest = df_subset.iloc[inds]
```